# Custom Area when importing a solution?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I have a solution and want to create a custom Area for that solution. I have created the Area but I want to have that area in all instances that I will install my solution but I don't want to override the sitemap that is in instance. I want to add only my custom area.  I

Answer (score 1):

Export the solution then go into the customizations.xml file and find the sitemap XML, remove all of the other areas from the solution except for your custom area. The result should be a SiteMap node with a single Area node. During import, your custom area will be added to the sitemap and existing areas will be left alone.

Optionally you could create a new solution with just the sitemap to make this manual editing process easier.